# Can I use Bigdata in ecommerce (Magento)?

Tags: hadoop, magento, bigdata, magento2

Can I use Bigdata in ecommerce (Magento)? we are having a custom website that extracts data from DB and displays it as report. But due to large data, timeout is happening…What can i do?

Comment: I suggest using a proper database that horizontally scales. Hadoop alone is not a database. Also Hadoop is not exactly PHP friendly, so there'll be lots of translation needing to happen if you did

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Big data in e-commerce.

But I don't think the problem you're solving is related to big data. Try generating the report on the server side (batch and store in a table) and use pagination to display the report on the website. If you have to generate the report on user action, try using materialized views or stored procedure to speed up the generation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use big data platform such as Hadoop and NoSQLs whichever best fit for your use case. In my work experience so far people used Hadoop back-end with BI tools like tableau and Qilikview etc.
Hope this will help.